# AP Prepayment Balance Report SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a SQL to generate AP Prepayment Balance Report in Oracle EBS r12. I think I need to use, `XLA_DISTRIBUTION_LINKS`, `AP_INVOICES_ALL`, `XLA_AE_LINES`, `XLA_AE_HEADERS`, `AP_SUPPLIERS`, `GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS` tables. Below is the SQL query I wrote to generate the report but there's something wrong since the output is not correct.

```
SELECT aps.vendor_name,
        invall.invoice_num,
        SUM (AEL.ACCOUNTED_CR) - SUM (AEL.ACCOUNTED_DR) AS INVOICE_SUM
FROM    XLA.XLA_AE_HEADERS              aeh,
        XLA.XLA_AE_LINES                ael,
        XLA.XLA_DISTRIBUTION_LINKS distlink,
        AP.AP_INVOICES_ALL            invall,
        AP.AP_SUPPLIERS                  aps
        GL.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS  glcc
WHERE  AEL.AE_HEADER_ID = AEH.AE_HEADER_ID
       AND AEL.AE_HEADER_ID = DISTLINK.AE_HEADER_ID
       AND AEL.AE_HEADER_ID = DISTLINK.AE_LINE_NUM
       AND DISTLINK.APPLIED_TO_SOURCE_ID_NUM_1 = INVALL.INVOICE_ID
       AND DL.AE_LINE_NUM = AEL.AE_LINE_NUM
       AND GLCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = AEL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
       AND APS.VENDOR_ID = INVALL.VENDOR_ID
       AND aps.vendor_name LIKE '%BETEKO%'
       AND invall.vendor_id = 407012
       AND TRUNC(AEL.ACCOUNTING_DATE)  <= '31-DEC-12'
       AND AEL.APPLICATION_ID      = 200
       AND GLCC.SEGMENT1   LIKE '13%'
       AND AEH.BALANCE_TYPE_CODE = 'A'
GROUP BY   APS.VENDOR_NAME,
           INVALL.INVOICE_NUM
 HAVING SUM (ael.accounted_cr) <> SUM (ael.accounted_dr)
```

Comment: What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: This doesn't look good: `AND GLCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID =` . There should be an expression after the `=`.

Comment: I've fixed the error in the script. The problem is that it's a little hard to explain the whole thing. The result of the query should be Prepaid balances grouped by the Vendor_name and invoice_num. What I get is wrong - meaning I don't get the right balance amounts for a given vendor ID. I am new to EBS and thus in the learning phase of the tables and schemas that make up Oracle EBS.

Comment: I saw a different SQL query written by another developer in our department and there he join `AP_INVOICES_ALL` to `XLA_DISTRIBUTION_LINKS` using `ALLOC_TO_SOURCE_ID_NUM_1` attribute of the latter. Why wouldn't he use `APPLIED_TO_SOURCE_ID_NUM_1` since as far as I know that is the link between the above mentioned tables